# How to change the ImageIO write Endianness

Tags: java, tiff, javax.imageio, endianness

Im writing the RenderedImage of PDF to a tiff file using

```
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(RenderedImage,"tif" ,file)
```

Im expecting my tiff file endian is little-endian, However it writes in big-endian, can help to explain how to change it to little-endian ?

Can also explain why the data written using big-endian take more size than original file size ?
I tried to convert the data to little-endian outside of my java code ,and the file size reduced drastically from 16 MB to 943 bytes.

Comment: Which TIFF plugin for ImageIO are you using? Using (my) TwelveMonkeys plugin, you can simply set the endianness (byte order) of the `ImageInputStream` using `stream.setByteOrder(LITTLE_ENDIAN)`. It also supports setting the byte order using the stream metadata passed to [`ImageWriter.write(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html#write(javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata,%20javax.imageio.IIOImage,%20javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam)). This way also works with JAI. However, I believe there's something completely wrong if you see such a reduction in size...

Comment: Im using TwelveMonkeys Plugin, Thanks for ur advise , Im able to set the Endianness , However I still have problem on setting compression, Can use the same plugin to set compression on the tiff ? and how to do that ?. I guess that's the reason the file size is bigger .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ImageIO API doesn't have a standardized way to specify endianness (byte order). How to do this, or whether or not it is supported at all, is plugin-dependent.

For the TIFF format, there exists multiple plugins (JAI, GeoTIFF, TwelveMonkeys, JDK9). All of the mentioned plugins (to my knowledge) supports setting the endianness using the stream metadata sent to [`ImageWriter.write(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html#write(javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata,%20javax.imageio.IIOImage,%20javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam)). The byte order is the only field you can set in the TIFF stream metadata.

```
ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIFF").next();
writer.setOutput(stream);

IIOMetadata streamMetadata = writer.getDefaultStreamMetadata();

IIOMetadataNode root = new IIOMetadataNode("com_sun_media_imageio_plugins_tiff_stream_1.0");
IIOMetadataNode byteOrder = new IIOMetadataNode("ByteOrder");
byteOrder.setAttribute("value", order == LITTLE_ENDIAN ? "LITTLE_ENDIAN" : "BIG_ENDIAN");
root.appendChild(byteOrder);

streamMetadata .mergeTree("com_sun_media_imageio_plugins_tiff_stream_1.0", root);

// ...

writer.write(streamMetadata, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
```

In addition, if not specified using the stream metadata, the TwelveMonkeys TIFF plugin will use the byte order from the `ImageOutputStream` it is writing to. Specifying the byte order this way is in my mind more straight forward, but obviously less compatible between plugins.

```
try (ImageOutputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(out)) {
    stream.setByteOrder(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

    ImageIO.write(image, "TIFF", stream);
}
```

---

Regarding the file size, most known TIFF plugins will write uncompressed image data by default. There is, unfortunately, no way to specify the compression settings directly using the `ImageIO` convenience methods, so any TIFF you write using these methods will be uncompressed.

The ImageIO API instead requires you to obtain an `ImageWriter` for the format you want to write to, and pass in an `ImageWriteParam` to specify the compression settings. Note that the types of compression supported may vary by plugin. Also note that which compression type that yield the best compression rate, varies depending on the image data you are trying to compress.

```
ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIFF").next();
writer.setOutput(stream);

ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionType("LZW"); // "Zlib", "PackBits", "JPEG", "CCITT T.4", "CCITT T.6" etc.
param.setCompressionQuality(0.5f); // Applies only to some compression types. Generally:
                                   // * 0.0 means highest compression
                                   // * 1.0 means best quality
```

You can query what compression types are available in the current plugin, using:

```
String[] types = param.getCompressionTypes();
```